# how to limit memory usage per process - UBUNTU / UNIX

Tags: ubuntu, memory, process, limit

I want to limit memory usage per process and get max memory usage since the process begin until it end.

UNIX - UBUNTU 14.04

Answer (score 1):

ulimit is the standard tool for this kind of things under linux. Please check the answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process).